# Mongo sort by parents AND children

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

Here's a tough one...
I am trying to sort mongo records. Essentially an inbox with conversations that some have replies.

So for example:

1. Message that was just sent
2. Message Replied to 1 day ago
3. Message that was received 5 days ago
4. Message that was sent 10 days ago AND replied to 9 days ago

I need to collect all message (replied to or not) and sort them by the last sent/received message.

My Message model has children (replies)

I can sort by created at for the original messages that were sent to the member just fine, but how do I sort a reply at the same time as the original message?

What I have so far:

```
@messages = Message.received(current_user).sort_by(&:created_at)
```

This gives me all the messages the member was sent (he is the received)
How do I go into each one of those and see what replies they have with what date and sort those together with the original messages?

I'm using mongoid with Rails.

Answer (score 0):

Stop torturing yourself and add a new `DateTime` on your `Message` to keep track of the `last_reply_at` which you default to the message's created_at when you create a new message. That's the only field to have to order by :)